# Add UIView and UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to make this, as in the first picture:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvc13.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIXx2.png)

But the view somehow does not show up like I want it to. Here you can see my full project code:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import CVCalendar

class Test: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var myTableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()
    var itemsToLoad: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    var myView = UIView()

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 4/255, green: 4/255, blue: 4/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.title = "Test"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Get main screen bounds
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 150)
        myView.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.addSubview(myView)



        myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight-50);
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.backgroundColor = .blue
        myTableView.layer.borderWidth = 3

        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return itemsToLoad.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.itemsToLoad[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("User selected table row \(indexPath.row) and item \(itemsToLoad[indexPath.row])")
    }
}
```

Why won't it show up? The first picture is how I want it, then second picture is how it looks now.

Comment: Start by setting `myView.backgroundColor = .black` and cutting the code about `myTableView`. Build and run. Does the black rectangle appear?

Comment: Also (sorry, don't mean to hammer you) please show how `myView` is declared / configured.

Comment: @matt - Yes, the black rectangle did appear on the top left.

Comment: And that is what we expect to have happen. So far so good!

Comment: Now add the table view code back in along with `myTableView.backgroundColor = .blue`. Maybe also `myTableView.layer.borderWidth = 3`. Build and run. Do you see the table view?

Comment: @matt Now It looks like this(added picture nr 2 in question). I have a navigationController witch is on the top there you can see., but the black view doesn't show up now. Also added my full code for you to see.

Comment: Well, the black view is probably hidden behind the black navigation bar at the top. You can use the View Debugger to confirm that. Okay, so my work here is done! The views are in fact appearing. Back to the planet Krypton!

Comment: @matt I see, how do I add the UIView below the navigationbar? I tried to do `myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, width: screenWidth, height: 150)`, but the a part of the navigationbar is still on top the the view.

Comment: You would use autolayout constraints to pin the top of the first view to the top of the safe area. (And everything else would need constraints too.) Using the _frame_ to position the views was always just wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if self.itemsToLoad[indexPath.row] != nil {
              cell.textLabel?.text = self.itemsToLoad[indexPath.row]
              cell.backgroundColor = .white

         }else {
               cell.backgroundColor = .blue

            }

        return cell
    }
```